# JQuery/JavaScript div tag "containment" approach/algorithm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Background: I've created an online circuit design application where div tags are containers that contain smaller div containers and so forth.

Question: For any particular div tag I need to *quickly* identify if it contains other div tags (that may in turn contain other div tags).

I've searched JQuery and I don't see any built-in routine for this.  Does anyone know of an algorithm that's quicker than O(n^2)?

Seems like I have to walk the list of div tags in an outer loop (n) and have an inner loop (another n) to compare against all other div tags and do a "containment test" (position, width, height), building a list of contained div tags.  That's n-squared.  Then I have to build a list of all nested div tags by concatenating contained lists.  So the total would be O(n^2)+n.

There must be a better way?

Comment: If you are that worried about speed, how about caching the amount of div's that particular div contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following checks

```
$('div_selector').has('div').length > 0 // it contains divs
```

alternatively

```
$('div_selector').is(':has(div)') // returns true if it contains divs
```

the above checks work for actual containment (*nesting*) in the dom (*not for visual containment where the dimensions of one div are contained in the other*).

Comment: (I actually asked the wrong question.  I created a new question regarding draggable div tags.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need jQuery. You can just do this test, where "div" is the container:

```
if (div.getElementsByTagName('div').length > 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I wish I could give "credit" for more than one correct answer in this system.  (I actually asked the wrong question.  I created a new question regarding draggable div tags.)